# value is not shown in a dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to edit a row in PHP, and one of the fields is a dropdown list that will get the value set for the chosen row (competence group), but the problem is that the selected option is empty, although the query works and I can also print the value using print_r. But when I have it in the form, it does not show anything.

I use this in the form:

```
<select  class="edit_competence_group" name="Competence_Group_Edit">
    <?php   
    $r=$this->matchinggroup;
    $Competence_Group=$r['Competence_Group'];
    print_r($this->matchinggroup);
    ?>
    <option selected="selected" value=<?php if (isset ($Competence_Group)) {echo $Competence_Group;}?>></option>
    <?php 
    $arr=$this->distinct_competence_groups;

    foreach ($arr as $row){

        echo "<option value='" .$row['Competence_Group']. "'>" .$row['Competence_Group'] . "</option>";         
    }
    ?>


</select>
```

the query to get the specific group is in a class as follows:

```
function editCompetence($Competence_id){
    if(is_numeric($Competence_id) && $Competence_id != 0){
        try{
            $this->query = "UPDATE Competences SET
                            Competence_Group=$this->Competence_Group
                            Competence_Class=$this->Competence_class
                            Competence_Description=$this->Competence_Description    
                            WHERE Competence_ID=$this->Competence_id";
            $tulos = $this->suoritaKysely();
            if(TESTITULOSTUS_LUOKKA){   echo 'Editing Competence with ID : '.$this->Competence_id.'<br/>Tulos: '.$tulos.'<br/>';    }

            if($tulos===false){
                return array('tulos'=>false,'viesti'=>'Competence could not be edited'.'<br />');
            }
            else return array ('tulos'=> true, 'viesti'=>'competence was edited'.'<br/>');

        }catch (Exception $e) {
            return array( 'tulos' => false, 'viesti' => _("tietokantavirhe").' :'.$e->getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

And I call the function in the index file:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit_id'])){
    echo $_GET['edit_id'];
    $oneC=$hr_object->matchingGroup($_GET['edit_id']);
    $page->assign('matchinggroup', $oneC);}
```

Comment: Make sure to enclose the selected `option` value with double quotes, as you do with the rest of the elements. For example `...value="<?=$Competence_Group?:''?>"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<select  class="edit_competence_group" name="Competence_Group_Edit">
    <?php   
    $r=$this->matchinggroup;
    $Competence_Group=$r['Competence_Group'];
    print_r($this->matchinggroup);
   if (isset ($Competence_Group))
     echo '<option value=" '.$Competence_Group.'" selected >your forgot the name here</option>';

    $arr=$this->distinct_competence_groups;

    foreach ($arr as $row){

        echo "<option value='" .$row['Competence_Group']. "'>" .$row['Competence_Group'] . "</option>";         
    }
    ?>


</select>
```